# Using Multiple Databases With iOS App

Tags: database, design-patterns, core-data, ios7

I have an iOS app that currently stores and pulls its data in/from SharePoint lists via a web service.  I want to have the option in settings for the app to also use another database or cloud database i.e. parse.com

I don't want to have to put if statements all throughout my code to test whether the app is set up to use either of the repositories.

What's the best way in an iOS app to architect it to use multiple repositories/databases to store and retrieve the data used in the app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Build a data manager class that handles the logic.  I would go so far as to create one for each service you are attaching to.  They can all inherit from a single base class and share the local cache code (which I am assuming is Core Data based on your tags).  Then on launch you can instantiate the one you want to use.

I would **NOT** use a Singleton as suggested.  Better to use Dependency Injection and be able to tear down and build up a new data manager if you switch between services while your application is running.  Using a singleton would be a poor design decision.

If you localize all of your network code into a single class (something I was speaking about last year as a Network Controller) you can then easily switch between services by keeping your interfaces the same.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  Yes the local cache will be core data.  I currently use AFNetworking to manage my networking calls - is this what you mean by "locallize all of your network code into a single class"?

Comment: No, I was recommending writing your own networking code and keep it contained in a single controller per server/service. If you want to use a third party library to replace 30 lines of code is your choice but the core solution is to have a single network controller class per service.

Comment: OK.  Thank you for the great advice.  I will leave the question open for another while in case there are other answers that build on top of your answer.

Comment: FWIW - here's the link to The slides of the talk. http://www.iosdevuk.com/storage/talks2013/MarcusZarraMVC-N.pdf

Comment: At the risk of pushing my luck ... do you have some examples of dependency injection that is referred to in your answer?

Comment: It's old but still informative: http://www.cimgf.com/2011/08/22/importing-and-displaying-large-data-sets-in-core-data/